# Controlling list items with for loops C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I am working on a small RPG game for a nephew, and I decided to throw in a handful of quests into the mix instead of just purely fighting skeletons. I built a working inventory in the fact I can add, remove and use items, however the items in the inventory will just fill up until the limit is reached (25 items) without stacking.

I remedied this with the following code:

```
finished = false;    
if(Backpack[bSlot].ITEM.ItemName == Item.ItemName){
                        if(!finished){
                            Backpack[bSlot].ITEM.ItemCount += 1;
                            finished = true;
                        }
                    }
```

which as you can see just checks if the item we're adding (Item) is the same as the one we have in the slot.

However this will only work if the item is exactly the same, any others are discarded and their gameobjects are distroyed.

Here is my function for adding items to the backpack:

```
public void AddItem(ItemDefine Item){
    bool finished = false;
    for (int bSlot = 0; bSlot < Backpack.Count; bSlot++) {
        //if slot is empty, add item
        if(Backpack[bSlot].ITEM.ItemName == null){
            if(!finished){
                Backpack[bSlot].ITEM = Item;
                finished = true;
            }
        }

        //If item is the same as the one in our current slot
        if(Backpack[bSlot].ITEM.ItemName == Item.ItemName){
            if(!finished){
                Backpack[bSlot].ITEM.ItemCount += 1;
                finished = true;
            }
        }

        //if the item is NOT the same as the one in our current slot
        if(Backpack[bSlot].ITEM.ItemName != Item.ItemName){
            if(!finished){
                Backpack[bSlot].ITEM = Item;
                finished = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My current problem is that I can't get it to check if the item is the same, if it is increase the amount (ItemCount) by 1, and if it isnt just iterate to the next list position and add the item there.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems. You should really be using `if else` for your logic.

However, there is a much easier way for you to do this using a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). A hash table will make it easier for you to avoid duplicates of items that you already have and will allow you to stack items that are stackable.

You can create a [**Dictionary**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
Dictionary<key, value>();
```

The `key` will be your item, the value should be a stack.

Comment: This helped out a little, I went back and rethought my idea out. tried using an if-else again and managed to fix it, but didn't need a Dictionary because an item has a counter as is (i.e ITEM.ItemCount) which is set as 1 from default (unless otherwise stated) and increased by using code.

Thanks for your response and help!

Answer (score 0):

I would finish the forloop before determining if it is in or not.

```
public void AddItem(ItemDefine Item){

  bool exists = false;
  if(Backpack.Where(x => x.ItemName == Item.ItemName).ToArray().Length > 0)
      exists = true;

  switch(exists) {
      case true: {
                     // Item Exists
                     ItemDefine newItem = Backpack.Where(x => x.Itemname == Item.ItemName).FirstOrDefault();
                     // we double check to make sure it really exists.
                     If(newItem != null) {
                        newItem.ItemCount += 1;
                     }
                 } break;
      case false: {
                     // Item Does Not Exist
                     Backpack.add(Item);
                  } break;
      default: {
                   // Something went horribly wrong
               } break;
  }

}
```

In this example we first search the list to see if an item with this name exists, if it does or not, we evaluate what we do afterwards.
If it exists we literally just increase the Item count else we just add it to the list,
Note that i dont know how you declared the Backpack varaible if it is an Array
or a List Backpack.

There are lots of ways to extend the logic, but the List where function is great for inventory handling.
Hope this gives some insight.

Comment: Didn't appear to work for me in all honesty, but it did give me a few things to think about. Which helped me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a good nights sleep, coming back and reading the answers. It got me thinking, I put my two sections of code, Adding New and Adding to the Item count in two for loops with the ideal amount of slots (5x5 grid, 25 slots) which didn't work. I had already tried else if statements prior which had given me some strange behavior.

I remedied the whole situation with one simple syntax change, instead of checking if the itemName was null I checked if the icon was null and thus the fix is as such:

```
public void AddItem(ItemDefine Item){
        bool finished = false;
        for (int bSlot = 0; bSlot < Backpack.Count; bSlot++) {
            //if slot is empty, add item
            if(Backpack[bSlot].ITEM.ItemIcon == null){
                if(!finished){
                    Backpack[bSlot].ITEM = Item;
                    finished = true;
                }
            }else if (Backpack[bSlot].ITEM.ItemName == Item.ItemName) {
                if (!finished) {
                    Backpack[bSlot].ITEM.ItemCount += 1;
                    finished = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works even up to the limit of the slots with each item type being accounted for in another piece of code i.e Weapons being limited to 1, food limited to 128, Resources 128 and quest items 1

Thanks for all your help (even if I didn't use them, it's great to know people actually help out)